# How to test that two vectors of histogram counts over the same bins come from the same multinomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution

**Preamble**:
When testing goodness of fit with null distribution with atoms using an EDF-based statistics $T_n$, random variable $n\sqrt{T_n}$ converges in law.

Empirically, the law observed with absolutely continuous null is different, than with purely discrete null.

I was assessing whether, given position of atoms (say integers 0 through 10), the distribution is the same for different weight assignments. So I generated samples from different discrete distributions, computed KS statistics, binned it, and was trying to compare counts to see if I can detect statistically significant differences.

Using *Mathematica*:

```
KolmogorovSmirnovStatisticFiniteBoundDiscrete[
   vec_ /; VectorQ[vec, IntegerQ], 
   {kmin_Integer, kmax_Integer}, 
   pvec_
] /; Min[pvec] >= 0 && Total[pvec] == 1 :=
Module[{cnt, pdfList, ecdf, ncdf},
  cnt = KeySort[Counts[vec]];
  pdfList = AssociationThread[Range[kmin, kmax] -> pvec];
  ecdf = Accumulate[
        Normalize[Values[KeySort[Merge[{cnt, 0 pdfList}, Total]]], Total]];
  ncdf = Accumulate[Values[pdfList]];
  Max[
     Abs[Most[ecdf] - Most[ncdf]],
     If[First[Keys[cnt]] == kmin, 0, 
         Part[ncdf, First[Keys[cnt]] - kmin]],
     If[Last[Keys[cnt]] == kmax, 0, 
         1 - Part[ncdf, First[Keys[cnt]] - kmin + 1]]
   ]
]
```

Generate KS statistics for discrete uniform nulls on $[0,5]$

```
With[{dist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 5}], n = 1600},
 stat1 = Sqrt[n] Table[
     KolmogorovSmirnovStatisticFiniteBoundDiscrete[
      RandomVariate[dist, n], {0, 5}, 
      PDF[dist][Range[0, 5]]], {100000}];]
```

Generate KS statistics for binomial null $\mathrm{Bin}\left(5,\frac{2}{3}\right)$

```
With[{dist = BinomialDistribution[5, 2/3], n = 1600},
 stat2 = Sqrt[n] Table[
     KolmogorovSmirnovStatisticFiniteBoundDiscrete[
      RandomVariate[dist, n], {0, 5}, 
      PDF[dist][Range[0, 5]]], {100000}];]
```

Plot histograms of statistics under different nulls:

```
Histogram[{stat1, stat2}, Automatic, "Probability", 
 ChartLegends -> {"DiscreteUniform", "Binomial"}]
```

[image]

These statistics have discrete values, for finite $n$, but in the large $n$ limit their cumulative distribution function should converge to an asymptotic continuous CDF.

I was investigating whether these limiting laws are going to be different for different discrete nulls, given both have the same support, as in the above example.

For this I partitioned the positive semi-axis into disjoint intervals, and recorded counts for statistics values in these experiments.

For example:

```
In[232]:= HistogramList[stat1, {{0, 0.4, 0.9, 100}}]

Out[232]= {{0, 0.4, 0.9, 100}, {19528, 65074, 15398}}

In[233]:= HistogramList[stat2, {{0, 0.4, 0.9, 100}}]

Out[233]= {{0, 0.4, 0.9, 100}, {32064, 58338, 9598}}
```

Now, given vectors of integer counts, under the null hypothesis that they arose as samples of the same unknown multinomial distribution, I would like to check if data contain evidence against it.

---

Hence my **question**:

I have two independent datasets of equal size, and for each of them I compute bin-counts for the common bins.

I hence get two multinomial samples $\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$ and $\{t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$. My null hypothesis is that these vectors are samples from the same population distribution.

What test would be appropriate to assess whether differences between $R$ and $T$ vectors can be attributed to randomness.

I am interested in the math part of the question, rather than in actual test computation.

Thank you.

P.S. Feel free to respond using R, Python or any other software package.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the math part". What mathematical thing are you after?

Comment: I am looking to understand the statistic one would choose to test the hypothesis. Given such statistics, I can work out its large $N$ distribution, where $N$ denotes the parameter in the multinomial population under the null. I was hoping the test would be a generalization of Pearson $\chi^2$, which somehow would not require one to know all parameters of the multinomial population distribution.

Comment: Perhaps I am overthinking this, and an EDF-based test applies, where EDF is built from the multinomial sample and the binning boundaries?

Comment: You seem to have a misapprehension about the chi-square. What makes you think you have to know all the parameters? If you'd choose an EDF test, are you implying that your are categories ordered?

Comment: Pearson's statistic $\sum_k (O_k - E_k)^2/E_k$ requires knowing $E_k = N p_k$. Does it not?

Comment: No; in particular, if $p_k$ is efficiently estimated under the null (where you only have only been given the counts after the binning), you still have a chi-square. The chi-square test of homogeneity is one case where you don't know (and needn't know) $p_k$. But I'm more concerned about these binning boundaries; what was binned and why? Again, are the bins (categories) ordered?

Comment: When testing goodness of fit with null distribution with atoms using an EDF-based statistics $T_n$, random variable $\sqrt{n} T_n$ converges in law. Empirically, the law observed with absolutely continuous null is different, than with purely discrete null. I was assessing whether, given position of atoms (say integers 0 through 10), the distribution is the same for different weight assignments. So I generated samples from different discrete distributions, computed A-D statistics, binned it, and was trying to compare counts to see if I can detect statistically significant differences.

Comment: Actually, this was with KS statistic, rather than AD

Comment: There's lots of information in your comment that should have been in your question, which presently doesn't describe what's going on. Please edit your question. With atoms, the EDF statistics don't converge to the usual asymptotic distribution for the continuous case and are not distribution free  (i.e. it's different for different discrete distributions). Change the probabilities in each category and you change the distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry it took me a while, but I rewrote the question to elaborate on the angle I was coming from.

Comment: Sound like you're asking for a two-sample goodness of fit test if that's the case there are any number of these, which have different power against different kinds of alternatives. If you can figure out what kind of differences are likely to arise in these circumstances, you could design your test to have good power against that. In particular, your histogram seems to suggest that something related to smooth tests of low order (but adapted to two samples, more like one based on partitions of a test of homogeneity than partitions of chi-squared goodness of fit) might be one good choice, ... ctd

Comment: ctd... though something like a two-sample version of an Anderson-Darling (again, without ignoring the impact of the discreteness) should do well. The KS would work okay but you might need somewhat larger samples to pick up the kind of smooth deviations you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to can be thought of as a contingency table test, I think.

Imagine a matrix. Each column is one of your bins (so, $n$ columns). Each row is one of your generating distributions (so, 2 rows). Your null hypothesis is that the rows and columns are independent--that the probability of being in row 2, column 3, is the probability of being in row 2 (1/2, assuming you generated equal numbers form each), times the probability of being in column 3 (which we hypothesize is independent of the row).

We decide beforehand how many are going to be in each row, so we have fixed row marginals. We do *not* decide how many are going to be in each column, so we don't have fixed column marginals. So what I usually use for contingency tables, Fisher's exact test, is I guess not really applicable--it assumes fixed row and column marginals. If you want ot try it anyway, it's fisher.test in R.

There's also the chi-squared contingency table, chisq.test in R. I don't know what the assumptions of this test are, though.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to see if the two distributions look the same and not whether or not they are independent.

Comment: I am testing whether the distributions look the same. Think about what it would mean for the row (source distribution) to be independent of the column (the bin). It would mean that the source distributions are the same (or at least, assign the same probability to each bin).